# Puppeteer - xpath - How to input text in div element using xpath?

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I have been struggling with this for a while but not avail.

I need to input some text in div element with xpath.

I am familiar with inputting text using id and names of elements. However, for inputting text into dynamic tables, unable to find a method using xpath. any help will be appreciated.

In the below code example, I am trying to input the text '0000'

```
const [ncm] = await cmtab.$x('//*[@id="sheet1"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div['+ d + ']/table/tbody/tr['+ r3 + ']/td[9]');
await cmtab.evaluate(ncm, (element, value) => element.value = value, "0000");
```

Should be able to input the text in the table using xpath. Please help as this would mean a lot for my project.

Comment: Check this out `await cmtab.evaluate((element, value) => element.value = value, ncm, "0000");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I tried the above, it went through without an error but did not enter the text in the element.
Tried with single quotes to the string to be entered but same result

`await cmtab.evaluate((element, innerHTML) => element.innerHTML = innerHTML, ncm, '0000');`

`await cmtab.evaluate((element, value) => element.value= value, ncm, '0000');`

Comment: Let me know if that works so I move that to an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried the above, it went through without an error but did not enter the text in the element. Tried with single quotes to the string to be entered but same result 

`await cmtab.evaluate((element, innerHTML) => element.innerHTML = innerHTML, ncm, '0000');`

`await cmtab.evaluate((element, value) => element.value= value, ncm, '0000');`

Comment: You might need to set the value to the `innerText` because a TD won't have a value property.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to write to xpath with innerText now.